# how to activate the TCP Fast Open in linux

Tags: linux, bash, sockets, tcp

I have 2 PCs linux (PC1: kernel 3.13.0-37 and PC2: kernel 3.11.0-12)

```
PC1-------PC2(TCP server port 4410)
```

From PC1, I m sending a tcp packet with TCP Fast Open (Fast Open Cookie Request)

[image]

I m expecting to get an answer from the server with TCP option (Fast Open Cookie: xxxxxxx) something like this:

[image]

But I got a tcp packet without the TCP option (Fast Open Cookie: xxxxxxx).

I m wondering if there is something to configure on my PC2 (linux) in order to activate the TCP Fastt Open option.

For the TCP server, I m running a php script:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

// Bind the socket to an address/port
socket_bind($sock, "0.0.0.0", 4410) or die('Could not bind to address');
for(;;) {
    // Start listening for connections
    socket_listen($sock);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I thought it would be a simple case of `sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen=3`. Since that's not it I removed my answer to help attract other answerers.

Answer (score 8):

You have to enable TFO in the server's listening socket with:

```
int qlen = 5;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_FASTOPEN, &qlen, sizeof(qlen));
```

(https://lwn.net/Articles/508865/)

Comment: In addition you have to enable TFO for listening sockets: `sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen=3`